# Camera pose to world coordinate transformation

Tags: slam, pose

I have managed to receive camera_pose for ORB-SLAM by following their code.

If I run

```
$ echo /world /camera_pose
```

I receive something like this:

```
Translation [-0.8, 0.66, -0.04]

Rotation in Quaternion [ 0.2, -0.3, -0.2, 0.2]

         in RPY radian: [0.071, -0.032, -0.34]

         in RPY degree [0.4, -25.09, -3.2]
```

Does this mean these are the translations and rotations of the camera_pose compared to the world coordinates?

How do I retrieve the estimate of the camera_pose in global coordinates (I want x,y,z,yaw,pitch, roll)?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to transform quaternion to euler angels you just need to use this equation:

```py
def quaternion_to_euler(q):

    (x, y, z, w) = (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3])
    t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + y * y)
    roll = math.atan2(t0, t1)
    t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)
    t2 = +1.0 if t2 > +1.0 else t2
    t2 = -1.0 if t2 < -1.0 else t2
    pitch = math.asin(t2)
    t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (y * y + z * z)
    yaw = math.atan2(t3, t4)
    return [yaw, pitch, roll]
```

I think translations are already in global coordinates.